# Subquery returning more than 1 row in db2 query

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I am using a insert query in which the subquery giving more than 100 record, due to which the insert is failing, is there any way I can insert all these 100 records in the table..
Query is:

```
INSERT INTO test values ((select id from test3), 'NEW')
```

Comment: You need to rephrase your query. Does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830312/insert-multiple-rows-using-subquery

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO test(`id`,`name`)
SELECT t.id,'New' FROM test3 AS t;
```

Comment: This answer is correct, except for the back ticks (`) around the column names.

Answer (score 0):

IBM documentation answers this question:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/sqlp/rbafymultrow.htm

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0000970.htm

P.S. In respond to remark in comment below (thanks for that):

```
   INSERT INTO T2 (intcol1,identcol2)
     SELECT intcol1, identcol2
     FROM T1
```

Comment: To prevent against link-rot, please pull any relevant examples into your answer.