# SQL Insert into table where subquery returns more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-insert

I have a query that uses subqueries to ascertain certain values. When there is only one result in the second sub-query it runs fine but when there is more than one possible result in the second sub-query it fails with a

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,
>   , >= or when the subquery is used as an expression error.

I want to insert a record for each of the multiple values that is identified by the second sub-query.

My code is as follows:

```
Declare @RoomID char (11)
Select @RoomID = min (RoomID) from tbRoom
While @RoomID is not null
begin
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbSurveyLocation]
   ([SurveyUID]
   ,[LocationParentID]
   ,[LocationID]
   ,[Comment]
   ,[SurveyParentTypeID]
   ,[CanSurvey]
   ,[Surveyed]
   ,[Status]
   ,[LastUpdate]
   ,[LastUpdateUser]
   ,[ClientCode])

VALUES

((SELECT SurveyUID FROM tbSurvey where SurveyTitle = 'CARLISLE PARK CRICKET PAVILLION')

,30

,(SELECT tbRoom.RoomID FROM         tbBuilding INNER JOIN
              tbBuildingLinkBusinessUnit ON tbBuilding.BuildingID = tbBuildingLinkBusinessUnit.BuildingID INNER JOIN
              tbBusinessUnit ON tbBuildingLinkBusinessUnit.BusinessUnitID = tbBusinessUnit.BusinessUnitID INNER JOIN
              tbFloor ON tbBuilding.BuildingID = tbFloor.BuildingID INNER JOIN
              tbRoom ON tbFloor.FloorID = tbRoom.FloorID
               WHERE tbBusinessUnit.BusinessUnitName like '%CARLISLE PARK CRICKET PAVILLION%')

,'',203 ,1,1,0,CONVERT(DATETIME, '10/01/2014 00:00', 102),'PDS 2014','~K2~')
end
```

I've checked the other similar answers on here but can't find anything that is directly related with various sub-queries as per my situation.

Comment: this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830312/insert-multiple-rows-using-subquery otherwise, why don't you get the 'subquery' first, add this to a list, and then do your second 'main' query?

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that and clearly must have got it wrong as I was still getting the same error. As for the sub-query / list option, I'm very new to this and don't know how sorry. Appreciate you taking the time to respond though

Comment: read over this: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/111401/nl

Comment: I've amended the code so that I'm getting each of the records (thanks for the pointers). How can I limit the time taken by the query as it's taking ages to run through the 10000 possible records? Thanks

Comment: how about adding indexes?

Comment: Can you show me a quick example please while I go off and research indexes (very new to this)

Comment: Hope you don't mind someone else coming along and making suggestions. In my experience, it's relatively rare to need a loop within SQL Server. So I'm wondering, since your loop contents involve inserting a single record and nothing else, whether a straight INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM ... might serve your needs better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should say up front that I don't know the larger context of your problem or how many records you need to insert. But, just based on the code you posted, this looks like it might better meet your needs:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbSurveyLocation]
([SurveyUID]
,[LocationParentID]
,[LocationID]
,[Comment]
,[SurveyParentTypeID]
,[CanSurvey]
,[Surveyed]
,[Status]
,[LastUpdate]
,[LastUpdateUser]
,[ClientCode])

SELECT  -- I'm going to keep this subquery because it isn't clear whether tbSurvey 
        -- is related to the rooms and business units in any way.
       (SELECT   Top 1 -- this ensures you only get one record back
                 SurveyUID
        FROM     tbSurvey
        WHERE    SurveyTitle = 'CARLISLE PARK CRICKET PAVILLION'
        -- If it matters which row you get, you can sort the survey with an ORDER BY here.
        )
     , 30
     , tblRoom.RoomID
     , ''
     , 203
     , 1
     , 1
     , 0
     , CONVERT(DATETIME, '10/01/2014 00:00', 102)
     ,'PDS 2014'
     ,'~K2~'
FROM   tbBuilding 
    JOIN tbBuildingLinkBusinessUnit ON tbBuilding.BuildingID = tbBuildingLinkBusinessUnit.BuildingID 
    JOIN tbBusinessUnit ON tbBuildingLinkBusinessUnit.BusinessUnitID = tbBusinessUnit.BusinessUnitID 
    JOIN tbFloor ON tbBuilding.BuildingID = tbFloor.BuildingID 
    JOIN tbRoom ON tbFloor.FloorID = tbRoom.FloorID
 WHERE tbBusinessUnit.BusinessUnitName like '%CARLISLE PARK CRICKET PAVILLION%')
```

What I just did will give you records for all the rooms that were associated with the business unit "CARLISLE PARK CRICKET PAVILLION".  If you need just one room, you could change the `SELECT` right under the target column list to `SELECT TOP 1`.  (That will give you an arbitrary room that meets the criteria; if you need a particular room, like the one with the lowest ID, use an ORDER BY clause at the end to control what room is the "top 1".)

Now, if you need to do something like link the survey title and the business unit name, so they are the same, and run this for all the surveys/business units, not just Carlisle Park, let me know in the comments.  If so, please let me know how many surveys you expect with the same survey title (One?  More than one?) and whether the number of rooms you expect for a given business unit is greater than one.

Comment: Ann L, you are a star. Thanks very much for helping out, it works perfectly. Can't believe how simple it was really and how I'd tried to overcomplicate it :-)