# MYSQL Error - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

when i use the way, it give error, where is the error??

```
INSERT INTO saturunler(user_id, type_id)  
VALUES ((SELECT id FROM uyeler 
), 8)
```

Comment: Your select query returns more than one row ,try using where condition with it.

Comment: there is no condition, i wanna add all users another table with different type id

Comment: Then you should create a procedure for that with loop

Comment: i tried but it still give the same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [insert multiple rows using subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830312/insert-multiple-rows-using-subquery)

Comment: here ;
DELIMITER //
 
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProducts()
BEGIN
   insert into saturunler(user_id, type_id) values ((SELECT id FROM uyeler), 8)
END //
 
DELIMITER ;

Comment: nope, one column getting from table, the second column getting only number within my query. so there is no more table. i put one variable after table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO saturunler (user_id, type_id)  
    SELECT id, 8
    FROM uyeler ;
```

Comment: What if the type id is variable?? for every row inserted

Comment: i tried it it give error "#1054 - Unknown column 'type_id' in 'field list' "8" "

Comment: @UmutBulut . . . You have to insert into correct columns.  The names come rom your question.

Comment: look, type_id should be match with number 8. i want to do only this but it give error.

Comment: oh thank you, it worked now, i forgot put "," :) thank you very much